# Disable External Storage (Thumb Drive) on Particular USB Ports

Tags: usb, permissions, security

A particular industrial computer has several USB ports accessible from outside the chassis and one USB port inside a secured door.

We need to restrict the accessible USB ports to use with mouse, keyboard and printer so that no storage device can be used on them.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command below:

```
#echo "blacklist usb_storage" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```